# Can anyone recommend PHP package for Simple Webmail?

Tags: php, open-source, package, webmail

I have a very simple website and would like to build an extremely basic and simple webmail system.  Inbox, send message, that's probably it.  I was hoping not to build it on my own, but could if it is the easiest option.  Can anyone recommend a simple opensource PHP package that can handle this?

*I should clarify that it only needs to be an internal mail system.  Doesn't need to send out to any external email addresses.  Just users sending to other users.  Not sure if that changes recommendations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page: http://www.noupe.com/ajax/10-ajax-webmail-clients.html

It looks like it has a good selection of choices. However, they will require JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a web mail system for you to embed into a larger web site, or a standalone system. (If you mean the latter, fairly common web mail systems are [Horde](http://www.horde.org/) or [SquirrelMail](http://squirrelmail.org/))

Comment: +1 SquirrelMail is the very definition of simple webmail

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a webmail system yourself you're going to have to look into the PHP IMAP module (http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php). Specifically the [imap_open](http://php.net/imap_open) function to connect to an IMAP server.

If you want to use something open-source built with PHP you have a few choices:

- SquirrelMail - http://squirrelmail.org/
- AtMail Open - http://atmail.org/
- RoundCube - http://roundcube.net/

Hope this helps,

- Christian